# Prisma ORM + PostgreSQL can't connect to sql database when deployed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, google-cloud-sql, prisma

In my deployed Node REST API service, I am seeing an unhelpful error when attempting to connect with  with one particular table (and not the others). The error reads "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')"

As I said, I can read and write to other tables without a problem. When I run the api locally, I can read and write to the problematic table (UserFavorite). I am connecting to the same instance of the database locally and from my deployed api.

My queries to those two tables are nearly identical. What am I missing here? Schema and queries pasted below.

SCHEMA:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt     DateTime       @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  clerkId       String         @unique @map("clerk_id")
  userFavorites UserFavorite[]

  @@map("user")
}

model UserFavorite {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  articleId String   @map("article_id")
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int      @map("user_id")

  @@unique([articleId, userId])
  @@index([slug, userId(sort: Asc)])
  @@map("user_favorite")
}
```

SERVICE:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function getUserByClerkId(clerkId: string) {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { clerkId }
    });
    return user;

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting user', err);
    throw err;
  }
}

export async function getUserFavorites(userId: number) {
  try {
    const favs = await prisma.userFavorite.findMany({
      where: {
        userId,
      }
    });
    return favs;

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting user favorites', err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

This problem popped up after I renamed the UserFavorite table. At first it seemed to be attempting to connect to the old table name. Since then, I have:

- deleted and reinstalled all my Node modules
- regenerated the prisma client
- dropped my entire database including all migrations and regenerated it from the prisma schema
- created a new database with a different name. doesn't work there either
- run `prisma format` on the Prisma schema using the Prisma CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh. It seems like I should be able to have a PascalCase entity in my schema, renamed to a snake_case table name in my database, and accessed in code as prisma.entityName. I am not sure why that isn't working, but the workaround I found is to just rename the table to `favorites` so I don't have to worry about casing.

Oh, I also added a postinstall script to my package.json, so that could have been what fixed it:

- "postinstall": "npx prisma generate"